# Keep Getting the UIAlert which ask for iTunes password

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, itunes

I have an iOS app which has in-app purchase and restore purchases functionality.

When I was testing the app in sandbox mode I use to get the alert all times asking for the password of iTunes account (UserName was already populated).

Now my app is live and I installed it and did the in-app purchase and then restored the purchases, So I am not in sandbox mode still I keep getting the alerts asking for password of iTunes account.

Following is a code which gives the ProductIds that I have purchased earlier,Then I pass those productIds to delegate which changes the status of those from 'Buy' to 'Purchased'

```
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
    //NSLog(@"Restored Transactions are once again in Queue for purchasing %@",[queue transactions]);

    NSMutableArray *purchasedItemIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //NSLog(@"received restored transactions: %i", queue.transactions.count);

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions)
    {
        NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
        [purchasedItemIDs addObject:productID];
       // NSLog (@"product id is %@" , productID);
    }

    if ( mDelegate != nil && [mDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(purchasedProductList:)] ){
        [mDelegate purchasedProductList:purchasedItemIDs];
    }

    [purchasedItemIDs release];
}
```

Any idea how to avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you completing the transactions? Show some code.

Comment: @Wain I Updated the question with code sample.I am completing the transaction when User has purchased it. I need to not to do that while restoring purchases right?or Do I need to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that `finishTransaction:` is called. It must always be called and calling it on a transaction multiple times is fine. If it isn't called, the transaction remains in the queue and the app will try to process it again later. It doesn't matter how the transaction was added to the queue, once it has been acted upon it should be 'finished'.

Note that when restoring new transactions are created, which are effectively wrappers around the original transactions, and they need to be 'finished'. From the restore docs:

> The payment queue will deliver a new transaction for each previously completed transaction that can be restored. Each transaction includes a copy of the original transaction.

Comment: The transactions are already finished when I purchased them. I am querying to SKPaymentQueue for all completed transaction and passing them to the delegate. All this transactions are already finished so whats is the purpose of making call to finishTransaction: again.

Comment: @mr.Wain can we call finishTransaction: like this in -(void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application{NSMutableArray *transactionsArray=[[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]transactions]mutableCopy];
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactionsArray)
    {
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:transaction];
    }} to finish all the current transactions when user terminates the application with out completing the transaction

Comment: @DineshReddyChennuru `applicationWillTerminate` is basically never called, and the transaction is sent to you after the purchase is made so you must process them and not just 'cancel' them.

Comment: @wain Basically my problem is I have to purchase a product and download it immediately.At this point where can i write finishTransaction: means in case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased: or case SKDownloadStateFinished: I am very new to IAP development so please kindly let me know how to do?

Comment: hai @wain here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693872/in-app-purchase-asking-old-account-password-while-restoring