# in-app Purchase asking old account password while restoring

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

When I opened app it's popup's iTunes login with out any interaction of user.That popup contains my old test user account mail id sometimes my current testuser mail id aslo.I heard that i have to call

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
```

I called it several times where ever I thought it's needed.But still it's asking password.
And here is my code:

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
{
    NSLog(@"Updated transaction %@",transaction);
    switch (transaction.transactionState)
    {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            [self errorWithTransaction:transaction];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
            NSLog(@"Purchasing...");
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
        {
          if(no need to download)
           {
             //  I will download the content later by restoring transactions.
               [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:transaction];
           }
          else
           {
               [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] startDownloads:transaction.downloads];
           }
         }
         case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
        {
           if(no need to download content)
           {
               [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:transaction];
           }
           else
           {
               [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] startDownloads:transaction.downloads];
           }
        }
           break;

        default:
           break;
    }
}
-(void) paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedDownloads:(NSArray *)downloads
{
for (SKDownload *download in downloads)
{
    switch (download.downloadState)
    {
        case SKDownloadStateActive:
        {
         //   showing download progress
        }
        case SKDownloadStateCancelled: 
        {
           [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:download.transaction];
        }
        case SKDownloadStateFailed:
        {
          //  showing alert and finish transactions
           [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:download.transaction];
         }break;
        case SKDownloadStateFinished:
        {
          //  processing content and finished the transactions
           [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:download.transaction];
        }break;
     }
}
}
```

Is this correct and is there any place to call **finishTransaction:** method.Please let me know is any...

thanks in advance..

Comment: When are you adding your observer? Are you catching your old transaction in the method you show? What status does it have?

Comment: when user selected to download content i will restore all the transactions and I will download the content from iTunes server based on the selected productId.And I am restoring transactions using following scenario `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];`

Comment: But when do you call `addTransactionObserver:`? Should be in `applicationDidFinishLoading:`

Comment: yes in `applicationDidFinishLoading:` also i given

Comment: And do you see the transaction at the observer and what status does it have?

Comment: when I opened the application from background it's not calling `updatedTransactions:` method.But it's just asking for the iTunes password.I tested in debug mode too...

Comment: What is logged if you get the `transactions` of the `SKPaymentQueue`? Can you see the 'bad' transaction?

Comment: from `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] transactions]` it's giving zero transactions.But when open the application from background it's asking for password..

Comment: So you have no way to cancel it until the password is entered and the transaction is completed with some status

Comment: in some cases you need to factory reset your test device to solve this issue

Comment: you need to log out from your apple account from settings menu, and then delete the app. On Subsequent app launch, try to make a purchase. Storekit will prompt you with an empty alert. Now enter the sandbox apple id you want to use. You are all set now.